# Is it possible to upload an iOS app with a wildcard app id to the iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have an app which acts as an "admin app" for one of my apps that is already in the App Store. I want this admin app to be distributed to someone I know. Sending updates of the admin app would be much easier if I could use the TestFlight program. Is it possible to upload the app to the App Store with a wildcard app ID? Or do I have to create a explicit App ID for this app as well (which will not be submitted to review and only used via TestFlight)?

Answer (score 2):

No, not possible, every app needs a unique bundle identifier and the related certificates and profiles.
See the [AppStore guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

No you must have a full unique app ID.  Also, you could issue that app as a B2B (Business-2-Business) app in order to still use the app store and have control over who can download it.  Your user will have to register as a business buyer in order to download it. But this would keep you from having to constantly reissue it every time the provisioning profile expires.